# Factory Reset but Can't Access Phone Due to 2FA

Tags: samsung

I had to factory reset my phonee due to forgetting my pattern. I am trying to get back into my phone, but in order to access the good account, it requires that I enter my passcode or get a text. However, I can't access my text since I am trying to get into my phone in the first place. What can I do to get back into my phone?

Comment: How did you factory reset it, if you cant get in.

Comment: It sounds as if you're describing [factory reset protection](https://www.androidcentral.com/factory-reset-protection-what-you-need-know). But if this is the case you normally just have to put in your Google account details after the reset.